# D3 js links length between image nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

Having the following graph:
[image]

When `mouseover` on node I'm showing only it's adjacent nodes and all other gets opacity 0.2 (transparency) - That's work fine.
The problem is that the links between the other nodes (with the opacity 0.2) is now appear and it's looks bad, because it override the image to the center of it. How do I make those links shrink to the image/circle edges?

```
var gSharedActivityGraphNodes = [{
    "id": 0,
    "image": "1285700-410.png",
    "height": 40,
    "width": 40,
    "adjacents": [1, 2, 3],
    "data": {
        "name": "Product1",
        "groupId": "Bla1",
        "desc": "Desc1",
        "leaderId": "123-123"
    }
}, {
    "id": 1,
    "image": "1228539-009.png",
    "height": 100,
    "width": 100,
    "adjacents": [0],
    "data": {
        "name": "Product1",
        "groupId": "Bla2",
        "desc": "Desc1",
        "leaderId": "123-123"
    }
}, {
    "id": 2,
    "image": "1277422-001.png",
    "height": 50,
    "width": 50,
    "adjacents": [0],
    "data": {
        "name": "Product1",
        "groupId": "Bla3",
        "desc": "Desc1",
        "leaderId": "123-123"
    }
}, {
    "id": 3,
    "image": "1272178-540.png",
    "height": 40,
    "width": 40,
    "adjacents": [0],
    "data": {
        "name": "Product1",
        "groupId": "Bla4",
        "desc": "Desc1",
        "leaderId": "123-123"
    }
}];

var gSharedActivityGraphNodesMap = {};

var gSharedActivityGraphEdges = [{
    "source": 0,
    "target": 1,
    "width": 5
}, {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 2,
    "width": 10
}, {
    "source": 0,
    "target": 3,
    "width": 1
}];

var width = 1300;
var height = 500;

var svg = d3.select("#sharedActivityGraph")
    .append("svg")
    .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height);

 var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
    .force("link", d3.forceLink())
    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-2000))
    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));


var links = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(gSharedActivityGraphEdges)
    .enter()
    .append("line")
    .style("stroke", "#ccc")
    .style("stroke-width", function (e) { return e.width });

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var node = svg.selectAll("foo")
    .data(gSharedActivityGraphNodes)
    .enter()
    .append("g")
    .call(d3.drag()
        .on("start", dragstarted)
        .on("drag", dragged)
        .on("end", dragended));

node.on('mouseover', function (d) {
       console.log(d);
       SharedActivityShowInfo(d);

       node.filter(function (d1) { return (d !== d1
       && d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) == -1);
       }).style("opacity", 0.2);
       node.filter(function (d1) { return (d == d1
       || d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) !== -1);
       }).style("opacity", 1);
    })
    .on('mouseout', function () {
       SharedActivityHideInfo();
        node.style("opacity", 1);
    });

var nodeCircle = node.append("circle")
    .attr("r", function (d) { return 0.5 * Math.max(d.width, d.height) })
    .attr("stroke", "gray")
    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
    .attr("fill", "white");

var nodeImage = node.append("image")
        .attr("xlink:href", function (d) { return d.image })
        .attr("height", function (d) { return d.height + "" })
        .attr("width", function (d) { return d.width + "" })
        .attr("x", function (d) {return -0.5 * d.width })
        .attr("y", function (d) {return -0.5 * d.height })
        .attr("clip-path", function (d) { return "circle(" + (0.48 * Math.max(d.width, d.height)) + "px)"});

simulation.nodes(gSharedActivityGraphNodes);
simulation
    .force("link")
    .links(gSharedActivityGraphEdges);

simulation.on("tick", function() {
    links.attr("x1", function(d) {
        return d.source.x;
    })
        .attr("y1", function(d) {
            return d.source.y;
        })
        .attr("x2", function(d) {
            return d.target.x;
        })
        .attr("y2", function(d) {
            return d.target.y;
        })
    node.attr("transform", function (d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"});
});

function dragstarted(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
    d.fx = d.x;
    d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
    d.fx = d3.event.x;
    d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
    d.fx = null;
    d.fy = null;
}
```

Comment: Can you share `gSharedActivityGraphEdges`?

Comment: @GerardoFurtado sure, my mistake, added

Comment: BTW, I think it would should be easy to apply the `opacity` only on the image and not on the node `fill` in `white` but I'm not sure how to achieve that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was about to post an answer showing how to recalculate the line x and y position. However, since you said [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45408172/d3-js-links-length-between-image-nodes/45408382#comment77776785_45408172) that just changing the opacity of the image (without changing the opacity of the circle) suits you, this is what you need:

```
node.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    node.filter(function(d1) {
      return (d !== d1 && d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) == -1);
    }).select("image").style("opacity", 0.2);
    node.filter(function(d1) {
      return (d == d1 || d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) !== -1);
    }).select("image").style("opacity", 1);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    node.select("image").style("opacity", 1);
  });
```

Here is your updated code:

```js
var gSharedActivityGraphNodes = [{
  "id": 0,
  "image": "https://www.guidedogsvictoria.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/guide-dog-710x570.jpg",
  "height": 40,
  "width": 40,
  "adjacents": [1, 2, 3],
  "data": {
    "name": "Product1",
    "groupId": "Bla1",
    "desc": "Desc1",
    "leaderId": "123-123"
  }
}, {
  "id": 1,
  "image": "https://www.guidedogsvictoria.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/guide-dog-710x570.jpg",
  "height": 100,
  "width": 100,
  "adjacents": [0],
  "data": {
    "name": "Product1",
    "groupId": "Bla2",
    "desc": "Desc1",
    "leaderId": "123-123"
  }
}, {
  "id": 2,
  "image": "https://www.guidedogsvictoria.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/guide-dog-710x570.jpg",
  "height": 50,
  "width": 50,
  "adjacents": [0],
  "data": {
    "name": "Product1",
    "groupId": "Bla3",
    "desc": "Desc1",
    "leaderId": "123-123"
  }
}, {
  "id": 3,
  "image": "https://www.guidedogsvictoria.com.au/wp-content/uploads/2016/09/guide-dog-710x570.jpg",
  "height": 40,
  "width": 40,
  "adjacents": [0],
  "data": {
    "name": "Product1",
    "groupId": "Bla4",
    "desc": "Desc1",
    "leaderId": "123-123"
  }
}];

var gSharedActivityGraphNodesMap = {};

var gSharedActivityGraphEdges = [{
  "source": 0,
  "target": 1,
  "width": 5
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 2,
  "width": 10
}, {
  "source": 0,
  "target": 3,
  "width": 1
}];

var width = 500;
var height = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body")
  .append("svg")
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height);

var simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
  .force("link", d3.forceLink())
  .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-2000))
  .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));


var links = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(gSharedActivityGraphEdges)
  .enter()
  .append("line")
  .style("stroke", "#ccc")
  .style("stroke-width", function(e) {
    return e.width
  });

var color = d3.scaleOrdinal(d3.schemeCategory20);

var node = svg.selectAll("foo")
  .data(gSharedActivityGraphNodes)
  .enter()
  .append("g")
  .call(d3.drag()
    .on("start", dragstarted)
    .on("drag", dragged)
    .on("end", dragended));

node.on('mouseover', function(d) {
    node.filter(function(d1) {
      return (d !== d1 && d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) == -1);
    }).select("image").style("opacity", 0.2);
    node.filter(function(d1) {
      return (d == d1 || d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) !== -1);
    }).select("image").style("opacity", 1);
  })
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    node.select("image").style("opacity", 1);
  });

var nodeCircle = node.append("circle")
  .attr("r", function(d) {
    return 0.5 * Math.max(d.width, d.height)
  })
  .attr("stroke", "gray")
  .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
  .attr("fill", "white");

var nodeImage = node.append("image")
  .attr("xlink:href", function(d) {
    return d.image
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return d.height + ""
  })
  .attr("width", function(d) {
    return d.width + ""
  })
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return -0.5 * d.width
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return -0.5 * d.height
  })
  .attr("clip-path", function(d) {
    return "circle(" + (0.48 * Math.max(d.width, d.height)) + "px)"
  });

simulation.nodes(gSharedActivityGraphNodes);
simulation
  .force("link")
  .links(gSharedActivityGraphEdges);

simulation.on("tick", function() {
  links.attr("x1", function(d) {
      return d.source.x;
    })
    .attr("y1", function(d) {
      return d.source.y;
    })
    .attr("x2", function(d) {
      return d.target.x;
    })
    .attr("y2", function(d) {
      return d.target.y;
    })
  node.attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
  });
});

function dragstarted(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
  d.fx = d.x;
  d.fy = d.y;
}

function dragged(d) {
  d.fx = d3.event.x;
  d.fy = d3.event.y;
}

function dragended(d) {
  if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
  d.fx = null;
  d.fy = null;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: @GerardoFutado I found problem with that solution when I later on add new links and nodes and `merge`. New links appear above the old nodes. Any idea how to fix that?

Comment: Please, post a *new* question, with all the relevant details. That way it will be easier to debug it and you'll have more users helping.

Comment: @GerardoFutado done. thanks! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47877091/d3-js-links-below-nodes