# D3 js links below nodes

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created graph object the creates graphs with can later on be extended with more nodes and links.
First creation looks good:

[image]

Then, with `add` function I've added node 4 and link:

[image]
as you can see above, the link of between node 4 and 3 is drawn above node 3 image/circle. How can I avoid that?
my source is code is [here](https://github.com/itayB/d3-graph/blob/master/index.js).

I'll attach most of it:

```
        function Graph(elementId) {
        var svg;
        var simulation;
        var mNodesData = [];
        var mEdgesData = [];
        var mNode = null;
        var mLink = null;
        var elementId;
        var heightDelta = 100;
        var width = window.innerWidth;
        var height = window.innerHeight - heightDelta;

        return {
            init: function () {
                svg = d3.select('#' + elementId)
                    .append("svg")
                    .attr("width", width)
                    .attr("height", height);

                simulation = d3.forceSimulation()
                    .force(".edge", d3.forceLink())
                    .force("charge", d3.forceManyBody().strength(-600))
                    .force("center", d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2));

                mLink = svg.selectAll(".edge")
                    .attr("class", "edge")
                    .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                    .style("stroke-width", function (e) {
                        return 1
                        /* e.width*/
                    });

                mNode = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .attr("class", "node");
            },
            clearGraph: function () {
                $('#' + this.elementId).empty();
            },
            getNodes: function () {
                return mNodesData;
            },
            getEdges: function () {
                return mEdgesData;
            },
            addNodes: function (nodes) {
                mNodesData = mNodesData.concat(nodes);
            },
            addEdges: function (edges) {
                mEdgesData = mEdgesData.concat(edges);
            },
            draw: function () {
                mLink = svg.selectAll(".edge")
                    .data(mEdgesData)
                    .enter()
                    .append("line")
                    .attr("class", "edge")
                    .style("stroke", "#ccc")
                    .style("stroke-width", function (e) {
                        return 1
                        /* e.width*/
                    }).merge(mLink);

                mNode = svg.selectAll(".node")
                    .data(mNodesData)
                    .enter()
                    .append("g")
                    .attr("class", "node").merge(mNode);

                mNode.call(d3.drag()
                    .on("start", dragstarted)
                        .on("drag", dragged)
                        .on("end", dragended));

                mNode.on('mouseover', function (d) {
                    function removePopup() {
                        $("#nodePopup").remove();
                    }

                    function showPopup(d) {
                        removePopup();
                        if (!d['data']) {
                            return;
                        }

                        var data = d['data'];
                        var htmlStr = '';
                        htmlStr += '<div id="nodePopup" >';
                        htmlStr += '    <div><button id="nodePopupCloseButton" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" style="font-size: 13px;"> </span> </div>';
                        htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupName">' + data['name'] + '</div>';
                        if (data['desc']) {
                            if (data['desc'].startsWith("http")) {
                                htmlStr += '    <a class="nodePopupLink" href="' + data['desc'] + '" target="_blank">Go to post..</a>';
                            }
                            else {
                                htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupDesc">' + data['desc'] + '</div>';
                            }
                        }
                        htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupGroup">GROUP: ' + data['groupId'] + '</div>';
                        htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupLeader">LEADER: ' + data['leaderId'] + '</div>';
                        htmlStr += '    <div class="nodePopupImage"><img src="' + d['image'] + '" style="width: 130px;" /></div>';
                        htmlStr += '</div>';

                        $("body").append(htmlStr);
                        $("#nodePopupCloseButton").click(removePopup);
                    }

                    showPopup(d);

                    mNode.filter(function (d1) {
                        return (d !== d1 && d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) == -1);
                    }).select("image").style("opacity", 0.2);
                    mNode.filter(function (d1) {
                        return (d !== d1 && d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) == -1);
                    }).select("circle").style("stroke", "#f6f6f6");
                    mLink.filter(function (d1) {
                        return (d !== d1.source && d !== d1.target);
                    }).style("opacity", 0.2);

                    mNode.filter(function (d1) {
                        return (d == d1 || d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) !== -1);
                    }).select("image").style("opacity", 1);
                    mNode.filter(function (d1) {
                        return (d == d1 || d1.adjacents.indexOf(d.id) !== -1);
                    }).select("circle").style("stroke", "gray");
                    mLink.filter(function (d1) {
                        return (d == d1.source || d == d1.target);
                    }).style("opacity", 1);
                })
                    .on('mouseout', function () {
                        // removePopup();
                        mNode.select("image").style("opacity", 1);
                        mNode.select("circle").style("stroke", "gray");
                        mLink.style("opacity", 1);
                    });

                var nodeCircle = mNode.append("circle")
                    .attr("r", function (d) {
                        return 0.5 * Math.max(d.width, d.height)
                    })
                    .attr("stroke", "gray")
                    .attr("stroke-width", "2px")
                    .attr("fill", "white");

                var nodeImage = mNode.append("image")
                    .attr("xlink:href", function (d) {
                        return d.image
                    })
                    .attr("height", function (d) {
                        return d.height + ""
                    })
                    .attr("width", function (d) {
                        return d.width + ""
                    })
                    .attr("x", function (d) {
                        return -0.5 * d.width
                    })
                    .attr("y", function (d) {
                        return -0.5 * d.height
                    })
                    .attr("clip-path", function (d) {
                        return "circle(" + (0.48 * Math.max(d.width, d.height)) + "px)"
                    });


                simulation.nodes(mNodesData);
                simulation.force(".edge").links(mEdgesData);

                simulation.on("tick", function () {
                    mLink.attr("x1", function (d) {
                        return d.source.x;
                    })
                        .attr("y1", function (d) {
                            return d.source.y;
                        })
                        .attr("x2", function (d) {
                            return d.target.x;
                        })
                        .attr("y2", function (d) {
                            return d.target.y;
                        })

                    mNode.attr("transform", function (d) {
                        return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"
                    });
                    mNode.attr("cx", function (d) {
                        return d.x = Math.max(d.width, Math.min(width - d.width, d.x));
                    })
                        .attr("cy", function (d) {
                            return d.y = Math.max(d.height, Math.min(height - heightDelta - d.height, d.y));
                        });
                });

                function dragstarted(d) {
                    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0.3).restart();
                    d.fx = d.x;
                    d.fy = d.y;
                }

                function dragged(d) {
                    d.fx = d3.event.x;
                    d.fy = d3.event.y;
                }

                function dragended(d) {
                    if (!d3.event.active) simulation.alphaTarget(0);
                    d.fx = null;
                    d.fy = null;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    function getData() {
        return $.ajax({
            url: 'api/v1/data.json',
            type: "GET",
        });
    }

    var graph = Graph('d3Graph');
    graph.init();

    $.when(getData()).then(function (data) {
        graph.addNodes(data.nodes);
        graph.addEdges(data.edges);
        graph.draw();

    });


    function add() {
        graph.addNodes([{
            "id": 4,
            "image": "images/4.jpg",
            "height": 20,
            "width": 20,
            "adjacents": [0],
            "data": {
                "name": "Number4",
                "groupId": "Bla4",
                "desc": "Desc4",
                "leaderId": "1234-1234"
            }
        }]);
        graph.addEdges([{
            "source": 4,
            "target": 3,
            "width": 1
        }])
        graph.draw();
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As svg elements are layered in the order they are drawn, the last drawn element will be the topmost element. As you add links after the original drawing of the force, links will overlap nodes. Two solutions come to mind:

1. Use .lower()

When appending a link, use `selection.lower()` to move it to the bottom (this moves the selected elements in the DOM so that they are under other elements):

```
svg.append("line")
  .attr(...)
  .lower();
```

2. Use multiple `g` elements

Use one `g` for the links, append this one to the SVG first. Use a second `g` for the nodes. Now rather than appending links and nodes to the same selection (the svg selection), just append them to their respective `g` selection. The order in which the `g` elements are appended now dictates the layering of your nodes and links irrespective of the order they were added to the visualization.